# Python. Difference between unicode+variable and u+constant?

Tags: python, unicode

Can someone please tell me how to fix this please.

This works:

```
    nOrd = (ord(u'ط'))
```

But this fails:

```
s="‎ط"   
s=unicode(s, 'utf-8')
nOrd = (ord((s)))
```

The error I get is:

*TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found*

Comment: What is the content of `s` prior to giving it to `ord`? `ord` expects a single character, you're apparently giving it a string of characters.

Comment: the context? its a character from a word from a tweepy stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `s` is simply *not the same text* as the first example:

```
>>> u'ط'
u'\u0637'
>>> u'ط'.encode('utf8')
'\xd8\xb7'
>>> s="‎ط"
>>> s
'\xe2\x80\x8e\xd8\xb7'
>>> s.decode('utf8')
u'\u200e\u0637'
```

You have a [U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+200e) character in the second example. That makes it *two* characters, not one.

You could remove it by stripping with [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) or by using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace); the first only removes it from the start, the other from *everywhere* in the string:

```
s = s.lstrip(u'\u200e')
# or
s = s.replace(u'\u200e', u'')
```

Comment: @BenderRodriguez: you could remove it after conversion with `s.lstrip(u'\u200e')`.